# Unable to paint a Jbutton on a border so that I can click on that to do some work

Tags: java, swing

What I need to do is to add a button to my border. So I can click on that to get some work done. I have given my source code. It is not painting my button. I don't know why.. What I expecting is to add some action to the button, make it clickable and mainly I need to enable or disable that button based on the needs. I tried with icon itself instead for button. I can't make it enable or disable when it is clicked. So if I can go for icon that is also fine. I need to get it done either with button or icon.

```
public class MyUI  implements Border, UIResource, SwingConstants{

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Icon i = new ImageIcon("home.png");
        JButton b = new JButton(i);
        //i.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
        b.paint(g);
        b.repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.plaf.UIResource;

public class MyUI implements Border, UIResource, SwingConstants {
    boolean isEnabledButton = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        JPanel borderPanel = new JPanel();
        borderPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        MyUI myBorder = new MyUI();
        myBorder.setEnabledButton(true);
        borderPanel.setBorder(myBorder);

        Object[]stringFor = new Object[]{"1","2", null};
        JComboBox compoBox = new JComboBox(stringFor);
        compoBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(compoBox.getSelectedItem() == null)
                {
                    myBorder.setEnabledButton(false);
                    borderPanel.repaint();
                }
                else
                {
                    myBorder.setEnabledButton(true);
                    borderPanel.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(compoBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(borderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Icon i = new ImageIcon("home.png");
        JButton b = new JButton(i);
        b.setEnabled(isEnabledButton);
        b.setBounds(0, 200, width - 200, height - 100);
        b.paint(g);
    }

    public void setEnabledButton(boolean isEnabledButton)
    {
        this.isEnabledButton = isEnabledButton;
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }
}
```